# iOS - Data saved in shared group extension folder is deleted in low storage scenarios. is this normal?

Tags: ios, realm, ios-extensions

I've had two users report to me that my database (realm) was suddenly empty, breaking the app.

My database is in a shared group extension folder so an extension can access it.

After talking with both of them, I determined that they both had very low storage on their phone <300mb.

I've been able to successfully reproduce the problem, by taking my phone down to ultra low storage, and then trying to install some apps from the app store.  I get warnings on my phone saying it can't install the apps which are caused by the low storage.

When I go back to my app, the database is gone.

If I change my database to not be in the shared folder, it is never purged.

This is where I'm saving my data

```
 let fileURL = FileManager.default
                .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myuniqueid.shared.database")!
                .appendingPathComponent("Library/Caches/default.realm")
```

Is this normal behaviour for shared group folders? Is data not safe there? Is this an issue with how Realm saves data to these folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm saving the database in a cache folder, which gets deleted.

I've moved the database and it is no longer deleted

```
let fileURL = FileManager.default
                .containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.myuniqueid.shared.database")!
                .appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
```